# Access properties of objects into nested Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested

I'd like please to retrieve all text (text 1,text 2....) from the following array :

```
[
    {
    "reviews": 
    [
      {
        "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e",
        "text": "My text 1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f",
        "text": "My text 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "reviews": 
    [
      {
        "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e",
        "text": "My text 3"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f",
        "text": "My text 4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "reviews": 
    [
      {
        "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e",
        "text": "My text 5"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f",
        "text": "My text 6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This array is stored in a variable called stores.

I have tried the following  :

`const listText = stores.map(count => count.reviews.text`   //  [null, null, null]
`const listText = stores.map((count, i) => count.reviews[i].text)`    //  Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
`const listText  = stores.forEach((key, i) => key.reviews[i].text)`   //  Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Could you please help me out here, 
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use  `count.reviews.text` as reviews is an array, so you should also iterate through reviews:

```js
const data = [
{
"reviews": 
[
  {
    "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e",
    "text": "My text 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f",
    "text": "My text 2"
  }
]
  },
  {
"reviews": 
[
  {
    "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e",
    "text": "My text 3"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f",
    "text": "My text 4"
  }
]
  },
  {
"reviews": 
[
  {
    "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e",
    "text": "My text 5"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f",
    "text": "My text 6"
  }
]
  }
]  

const listText = data.reduce((acc,current) => acc.concat(current.reviews.map(it => it.text)), [])

console.log(listText)
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly :) Thanks.  

And what about if I wanted to pick just some values from the array and not others ?  
In my example, I have just  `_id` and `text`. But suppose I have also other properties such as `photo`, `slug`.... How can I make sure to pick just `_id` and `text` but NOT the other properties ?

Comment: Could you please clarify the desired output? if you have an array of objects with lots of fields and you need to convert it to list of objects with just 2 fields? e.g. `const initialArr = [{id:1, text:'abc', rank:5, etc:'some vale'}, {id:2, text:'rwr', rank:3, etc:'some vale'}, {id:3, text:'36y3563', rank:6, etc:'some vale'}]` you  can use .map function: `initialArray.map(item=> ({id: item.id, text:item.text}))`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. You've been very helpful Elivra, many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Map and flat:

```js
const data = [ 
{ "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 1" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 2" } ] }, 
{ "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 3" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 4" } ] }, 
{ "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 5" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 6" } ] } ] 
console.log(
  data.map(items => items.reviews.map(review => review.text)).flat()
)
```

Comment: Without using `.flat()` it works, even though I get arrays into array. But when using `.flat()`, I log `flat is not a function`.  
Thanks @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), you can iterate over each object and then `.map()` the reviews array of each object to an array of containing the text properties. `.flatMap()` allows you to flatten all the inner map array results into the one larger resulting array.

```js
const stores = [ { "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 1" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 2" } ] }, { "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 3" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 4" } ] }, { "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 5" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 6" } ] } ];

const res = stores.flatMap((o) => o.reviews.map(({text}) => text));
console.log(res);
```

If you can't support `.flatMap()`, you can always map to an array of arrays, using `.map()` and then flatten it after using [`.concat()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=concat%20mdn&oq=conat%20mdn&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.3652j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`):

```js
const stores = [ { "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 1" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 2" } ] }, { "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 3" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 4" } ] }, { "reviews": [ { "_id": "5e84239d6e24358b50f3fe4e", "text": "My text 5" }, { "_id": "5e8423a46e24358b50f3fe4f", "text": "My text 6" } ] } ];

const res = [].concat(...stores.map((o) => o.reviews.map(({text}) => text)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Perfect, it works perfectly @Nick Parsons.  
You've made my day :)
Great explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
let output = [];
            input.map(function (item_1) {
                item_1.reviews.map(function (item_2) {
                  output.push(item_2.text);
                })
            });
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Kulkarni :)